# Mineração de Dados - testes estatístico para comparação do resultado de classificadores

Tags: inteligência-artificial

tenho que utilizar um teste estatístico para comparar o resultado de vários classificadores. O problema é que não sei qual teste estatístico usar, pois tenho acesso apenas a média e o desvio padrão do resultado de cada classificador.

Resultados dos algoritmos:

Naive Bayes:
 - Média: 97,50
 - Desvio Padrão: 7,91

C4.5:
 - Média: 77,50
 - Desvio Padrão: 23,71

SVM:
 - Média: 98,00
 - Desvio Padrão: 6,32

1-NN:
 - Média: 75,50
 - Desvio Padrão: 21,27

3-NN:
 - Média: 77,00
 - Desvio Padrão: 17,51

5-NN:
 - Média: 75,00
 - Desvio Padrão: 23,69

7-NN:
 - Média: 73,00
 - Desvio Padrão: 18,74

Alguma ideia de teste paramétrico que possa comparar os resultados desses algoritmos só com essas informações ?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo Leonardo Amaral, embora isso não tenha nada a ver com o foco do site, vou deixar uma resposta. Se a resposta for útil, basta marcar como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079. Importante que saiba também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

### Os conceitos

**A média aritmética** tomada sozinha é uma ferramenta perigosa. Em um conjunto de dados com um alto número de outliers* ou uma distribuição distorcida, a média simplesmente não fornece a precisão necessária para uma decisão acertada.

*Os outliers são dados que se diferenciam drasticamente de todos os outros, são pontos fora da curva. Em outras palavras, um outlier é um valor que foge da normalidade e que pode (e provavelmente irá) causar anomalias nos resultados obtidos por meio de algoritmos e sistemas de análise.

**O desvio padrão** traduz a variação de um conjunto de dados em torno
da média, ou seja, da maior ou menor variabilidade dos resultados obtidos. Permite
identificar até que ponto os resultados se concentram ou não ao redor da tendência
central, ou média,  de um conjunto de observações. Quanto maior for a dispersão, menor é a concentração e viceversa.

> Um pequeno desvio padrão pode ser um objetivo em certas situações em que os resultados são limitados, por exemplo, na fabricação de produtos e controle de qualidade. Um tipo particular de parte do carro que tem que ser de 2 centímetros de diâmetro para se ajustar adequadamente não deve ter um desvio padrão muito grande, durante o processo de fabrico. Um desvio padrão grande neste caso significaria que muitas partes acabam no lixo, porque eles não se encaixariam direito; ou isso ou os carros terão problemas no caminho.

Em uma distribuição normal perfeita, 68,26% das ocorrências se concentrarão na área do gráfico demarcada por um desvio padrão à direita e um desvio padrão à esquerda da linha média

[image: distribuição desvio padrão]

---

---

### No seu caso, que não sei bem do que se trata, temos:

seja M a média e DP o desvio padrão

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 classificador      DP       M-DP          M         M+DP
 ------------------------------------------------------------
     Naive         7,91     89,59        97,50      105,41
     C4.5          23,71    53,79        77,50      101,21
     SVM           6.32     91,68        98,00      104,32
     1-NN          21,27    54,23        75,50      96,77
     3-NN          17,51    59,49        77,00      94,51
     5-NN          23,69    51,31        75,00      98,69
     7-NN          18,74    54,26        73,00      91,74
```

O que podemos concluir?

Aproximadamente 68% do classificador `Naive` se concentram entre `89,59` e `105,41`

Aproximadamente 68% do classificador `C4.5` se concentram entre `53,79` e `101,21`

Aproximadamente 68% do classificador `SVM` se concentram entre `91,68` e `104,32`

E assim sucessivamente .....

Então se queremos um classificador com 68% entre 92 e 100, certamente seria `SVM`

Você pode dar continuidade a tabela colocando os valores de `M-2DP` e `M+2DP`

Quando demarcamos dois desvios padrão, para a direita e a esquerda da média, abrangemos 95,44% das ocorrências e 99,72% quando demarcamos três.

Comment: Na hora da conclusão você se enganou, C4.5 é de `53,79` e `101,21` SVM é de `91,68` e `104,32` portanto, acho, que SVM seria o classificador com 68% entre `92 e 100`. Fora isso, deu para entender os fundamentos.

Comment: Resposta editada